# Why does searching for a string of n space characters return inconsistent results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Customer found a bug and while attempting to fix it I came across this odd behaviour.  I've spent several hours running different tests against this and I'm still struggling to understand it.  It is definitely reproducable on SQL2016 and 2017 (latest CU) and different versions of management studio.  Example below is a simplified example taken from a 1000 line proc:

To start create the necessary objects:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO
USE TestDB;
CREATE TABLE test (
id int IDENTITY,
pdate datetime);
INSERT test
VALUES('1-Feb-2018'),('1-Mar-2018'),(NULL);
```

Now have a quick look to verify the values in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

Now I want to convert pdate into a specifc format, and return an empty string if pdate is NULL:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            IIF(pdate IS NULL, '', FORMAT(pdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) pdate2
        FROM test
    ) a
WHERE pdate2 = ''
```

The above query produces id 3 with an empty string, the expected result.  But when I put any number of space characters between the quotation marks I still get the same row in the results:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            IIF(pdate IS NULL, '', FORMAT(pdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) pdate2
        FROM test
    ) a
WHERE pdate2 = '    '
```

Why would this happen?

If instead of equals I use LIKE without wildcard, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
            id,
            IIF(pdate IS NULL, '', FORMAT(pdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) pdate2
        FROM test
    ) a
WHERE pdate2 LIKE '    '
```

This gives me the expected result - no rows returned.

Is this a bug, or is there some deep technical reason why an empty string can be considered equal to a string of n space characters?  If so then why does LIKE give me the correct result?

Comment: Aside: From  [`Len()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql): "Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**." [`DataLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql) does not exclude trailing blanks. For Unicode strings you can use `DataLength( UnicodeStringExpression ) / DataLength( N'#' )` to get the length in characters. In general `DataLength( Left( Coalesce( StringExpression, '#' ), 1 ) )` will return the number of bytes per character.

Comment: That's cool, I wish I knew this yesterday when I was testing!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the ANSI SQL standard, trailing whitespace is often ignored for character field comparisons.  So this:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE '' = '     '
```

Will return `1`.

[KB316626 INF: How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316626/inf-how-sql-server-compares-strings-with-trailing-spaces)
 describes this behavior (emphasis mine):

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   <Comparison Predicate>, General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. **The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them.** The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.
>
> The only exception to this rule is the LIKE predicate. When the right
>   side of a LIKE predicate expression features a value with a trailing
>   space, SQL Server does not pad the two values to the same length
>   before the comparison occurs. Because the purpose of the LIKE
>   predicate, by definition, is to facilitate pattern searches rather
>   than simple string equality tests, this does not violate the section
>   of the ANSI SQL-92 specification mentioned earlier.
>
> [...]
>
> The SET ANSI_PADDING setting does not affect whether SQL Server pads
>   strings before it compares them. SET ANSI_PADDING only affects whether
>   trailing blanks are trimmed from values being inserted into a table,
>   so it affects storage but not comparisons.

Note that they also cover the discrepancy you're finding with LIKE.

Brent Ozar blogs about this behavior [here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/04/surprising-behavior-trailing-spaces/).

Comment: This answers my question perfectly.  I still find it a bit confusing that an empty string can be considered "equal" to a string containing only space characters.  Glad there is an explanation for it though and that I'm not losing my marbles.  Thank you.

Comment: @MrWest It may be helpful to remember that, originally, CHAR was the only data type for string data in SQL.  That is to say, originally all character data was always padded to the full length of the field.  VARCHAR was added later.